# Complex manifolds with corner?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, several-complex-variables, smooth-manifolds, complex-manifolds

I was reading Dominic Joycee [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3518) on Manifold with corner.  He talk about manifold with corner modeled over $[0,\infty)^k\times \mathbb R^{n-k}$ for some $k\leq n$.  From here I moved to Melrose unpublished book on Manifold with corner.

Is the theory for Complex manifold with boundary and corner developed?  I mean is there some literature available where complex manifold with corner has been discussed?

"Complex manifold with corner"  is a vague word.  But I mean, i want to see as $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ as complex manifold with corner where boundary is CR manifold.

I think "main problem" is the extension of holomorphic function defined in the interior of domain.  In real case, we have Whitney extension theorem.... There may be many other issues...  Can I have references, suggested reading along these lines?  Thanks

Comment: Could you by any chance direct me to a copy of the unpublished book of Melrose mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some related results about compact Stein 4-manifolds with boundary as Lefschetz fibrations over the disk (whose fiber has non-empty boundary). Corners in this case arise naturally on the total space. References includes Loi-Piergallini's theorem, and subequent works of Akbulut-Ozbagci (simply google with these keywords).